# Why some widgets do not get included in WindowBuilder?

Tags: eclipse, swt

Im using WindowBuilder tool to build a GUI for my application and I see that some widgets or tools don't get included in the Design view. In my case, I have created a new SWT Application window and I try to add DropDown Menu in the Application window and I always get a `red` icon when I take the DropDown menu from the palette to the design area. Can anyone tell me what is the problem in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake I was doing...It is not possible to directly add a DropDown Menu in the design editor. You first have to add a Menu and then add a DropDown Menu. And the widgets do work in all forms of applications you want to develop.